# The parameters requested by GET are pasted together

Tags: php, nginx, yii2

The client requests `http://www.example.com` and passes the parameters via GET, and the final request is `http://www.example.com/api/page?timestamp%3D1485404388%26sign%3De91a73150d87ebcb3ae00a26d85ce93b`.

#### Normal situation

````
```
$_GET = [
     'timestamp' => 1485404388,
     'sign' => 'e91a73150d87ebcb3ae00a26d85ce93b'
]
```
````

#### Abnormal situation

````
```
$_GET = [
     'timestamp=1485404388&sign=e91a73150d87ebcb3ae00a26d85ce93b' => ''
]
```
````

#### $_SERVER

````
```
'REQUEST_URI' => '/api/page?timestamp%3D1485404388%26sign%3De91a73150d87ebcb3ae00a26d85ce93b'
```
````

This situation will not happen 100%, by looking at the log I found this problem, I suspect that the client is the problem, but can not determine where the problem is in the end.

web.php

````
```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
```
````

nginx.conf

````
```
server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        root   /www/example/web;
        index   index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log /www/log/nginx/access_example.log;
        #error_log /www/log/nginx/error_example.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root   /www/example/web;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            log_not_found  off;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/local/nginx/html;
        }
}
```
````

Comment: The problem is that `%26sign%3D` is URL encoded so is seen as part of the `timestamp` value and not `&sign=`.

Comment: Why not all the requests are so, but some of the requests will be so?

Comment: I think is client problem, sometimes encoded & to %26 in url. Search this problem rather in client side.

Comment: Yes,I think is client problem too.